# Why do I get one less than $2^k$?

Tags: combinations

I have four letters, $A B C D$ , and I need all possible combinations when the order doesn't matter.

I thought this should be $2^k$ , with $ k$ being $4 $ .

But I can only count $15$, is there a reason for this? Am I missing one?

```
A
B
C
D
A,B
A,C
A,D
B,C
B,D
C,D
A,B,C
A,B,D
A,C,D
B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

Comment: case with no letters

Comment: Don't you mean "I can only count 15" ???

Comment: yes thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You count 15 not 16....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the combination containing no letters at all. A set of $k$ elements has $2^k$ subsets, but only $2^k - 1$ non-empty subsets.

Answer (score 0):

$2^k$ is due to the fact that you can take or not take the letters independently, so every binary choices multiply with each other. One of the combinations is "take none".